# Android new google maps app parallax behavior - how to do it?

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I need to implement a UI that kinda looks like new google maps for Android.

However, I'm not having so much success implementing this behavior:
The map should be static when the tabs are above half of the screen's height, and should parallax when the tabs below half of the screen's height.

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                 android:id="@+id/main_content"
                                                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                 android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#abcdef"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#abcdef"
                android:elevation="3dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="APP"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ABCCAA"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ABCCAA">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#FFAA33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TAB 1"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TAB 2"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and here is how it looks like:

[image]

I guess it should be done by playing with collapse mode programmatically, based on the tabs Y offset, but it is not working even when I change it in XML.

Playing with layout_collapseMode of the map fragment doesn't help.
When set it to parallax, the map always parallax, and when set it to pin/none, the map is always getting scrolled.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you get any success??